# How to make button and background flash in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-controls

### Issue

---

The issue I am having is when a user clicks a button I want the button to start flashing from 100% visible to around 20% visible and the background of the WPF window to change colors from `#ffffff` to `#d6786a` and this should happen untill the button is clicked again. Then the animations should stop.

### Code

---

I have done a bit of diging around to find where somone has done this and I can't seem to see anything. The code i have at the moment is as follows.

Here is the button I want to flash from 100% visible to 20% visible when clicked:

```
<Button Name="button2" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Visibility="{Binding VisableState, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" ToolTip="Start Live Stream" Command="{Binding PlayStream}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5" Height="22" Width="22" >
    <Image Source="../Images/recordicon.png"/>
</Button>
```

I have tried to add a storyboard into the button and it just didn't work:

```
<Button.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="button2" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Visibility)">
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
  </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

I am new to WPF so going into animation is more difficult for me. If anyone could give me a little help on this stage it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define animations in resources for example like this

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlashButton" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeColor">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeColor2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

and create handler for button click

```
        private bool isRunning;
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var flashButton = FindResource("FlashButton") as Storyboard;
        var changeColor = FindResource("ChangeColor") as Storyboard;
        var changeColor2 = FindResource("ChangeColor2") as Storyboard;

        if (isRunning)
        {
            flashButton.Stop();
            changeColor2.Begin();
            isRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flashButton.Begin();
            changeColor.Begin();
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer the code seems to work fine. Is it possible for me to call the FindResource from the ViewModel? and not the code behind?

Comment: I also get `'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.` when i begin the `changeColor ` stroyboard.

Comment: ofc not... in that case you need to do it differently. for example create two events BeginAlert, EndAlert and raise them in your VM, your view should be subscribed to these events and react to them accordingly.

Comment: @BenClarke and do you have grid named grid in that View? Everything should work just fine, if you just copy and use my code.

Comment: I didn't add the background to the grid that's why it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To change *"visibility to around 20%"* you have to *animate* [`Opacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) property (`double` type from `0.0` to `1.0`) not `Visibility` (`enum` with 3 values, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The goal can be easily achieved if you can use `ToggleButton` (because of its nice `Checked` and `Unckecked` routed events):

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="storyboard">
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            AutoReverse="True">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="0.2"
                                     Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="storyboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
```